# SQL: Join columns to rows without PIVOT efficiently

Tags: sql, database, join, select, pivot

I have the following two tables. Each Object can have 0-4 corresponding Attributes, which are stored in the Attributes table.

#### Objects

| ID | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha |
| 2 | Beta |
| 3 | Gamma |

#### Attributes

| ID | ObjectID | AttributeName | AttributeValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | K1 | 12345 |
| 2 | 1 | K2 | 23456 |
| 3 | 2 | K1 | 34567 |
| 4 | 3 | K2 | 45678 |
| 5 | 3 | K3 | 56789 |
| 6 | 3 | K4 | 67890 |

Now I want the following result, where for every possible Attribute a column is created which contains either the corresponing Attribute or NULL.

#### AttributedObjects

| ID | Title | K1 | K2 | K3 | K4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alpha | 12345 | 23456 |  |  |
| 2 | Beta | 34567 |  |  |  |
| 3 | Gamma |  | 45678 | 56789 | 67890 |

I came up with two queries, which produce the wanted result. The database I'm forced to work with **doesn't support the PIVOT clause**. Under these circumstances, which of the following two is more efficient for the wanted result?

##### Query based on SELECT

```sql
SELECT ID, Title,
    (SELECT AttributeValue FROM Attributes WHERE AttributeName = "K1" AND ObjectID = Objects.ID) AS K1,
    (SELECT AttributeValue FROM Attributes WHERE AttributeName = "K2" AND ObjectID = Objects.ID) AS K2,
    (SELECT AttributeValue FROM Attributes WHERE AttributeName = "K3" AND ObjectID = Objects.ID) AS K3,
    (SELECT AttributeValue FROM Attributes WHERE AttributeName = "K4" AND ObjectID = Objects.ID) AS K4
FROM Objects;
```

##### Query based on JOIN

```sql
SELECT Objects.ID, Objects.Title, Q1.K1, Q2.K2, Q3.K3, Q4.K4
FROM (((Objects 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ObjectID, AttributeValue AS K1 FROM Attributes WHERE AttributeName = "K1")
        AS Q1 ON Objects.ID = Q1.ObjectID)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ObjectID, AttributeValue AS K2 FROM Attributes WHERE AttributeName = "K2")
        AS Q2 ON Objects.ID = Q2.ObjectID)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ObjectID, AttributeValue AS K3 FROM Attributes WHERE AttributeName = "K3")
        AS Q3 ON Objects.ID = Q3.ObjectID)
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT ObjectID, AttributeValue AS K4 FROM Attributes WHERE AttributeName = "K4")
        AS Q4 ON Objects.ID = Q4.ObjectID;
```

Comment: Neither is optimal, use *conditional aggregation*

Comment: @Stu I agree with him. And please describe which database you use; PostgreSQL, MySQL etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `conditional aggregation` as follows:

```
select o.id, o.title,
    Max(case when AttributeName='K1' then AttributeValue end) K1,
    Max(case when AttributeName='K2' then AttributeValue end) K2,
    Max(case when AttributeName='K3' then AttributeValue end) K3,
    Max(case when AttributeName='K4' then AttributeValue end) K4
from objects o
join attributes a on a.ObjectID = o.id
group by o.Id, o.title
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose one more alternative which seems more efficient using `IF` or `CASE` and `GROUP BY`, so you don't have to pivot anything. Because I don't know what you do with those values, I used `SUM`. See the following:

```
SELECT Title,
       SUM(IF(AttributeName = 'K1', AttributeValue, 0)) AS K1,
       SUM(IF(AttributeName = 'K2', AttributeValue, 0)) AS K2,
       SUM(IF(AttributeName = 'K3', AttributeValue, 0)) AS K3,
       SUM(IF(AttributeName = 'K4', AttributeValue, 0)) AS K4
FROM AttributedObjects AS AO
INNER JOIN Attributes AS A ON AO.ObjectID = O.ID
GROUP BY Title
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pivot` with `Join`

```
SELECT ID,Title, 
  K1,K2,K3,K4  
FROM  
(
  SELECT o.ID,Title,AttributeName, AttributeValue   
  FROM Objects o
  JOIN Attributes a ON o.ID = a.ObjectID
) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
  AVG(AttributeValue)  
  FOR AttributeName IN (K1,K2,K3,K4)  
) AS PivotTable;
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=25240804225602969e7f8c27b5851384)

Comment: the OP specifically said that he can't use PIVOT